# What is the difference between launch.json and task.json in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why do we have two configurations to setup the build environment in Visual Studio Code? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Tasks are defined in a workspace tasks.json file and VS Code has templates for common task runners. In the Command Palette (⇧⌘P), you can filter on 'task' and can see the various Task related commands. and launch configuration file - launch.json. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They are not both used to setup the build configuration.

`launch.json` is used for to launch an app for debugging. It has settings geared for things like mapping to your workspace source code or defining the Chrome port to use.

To use a configuration from `launch.json`, you select it on the Debug panel and click the run button.

`tasks.json` is used to execute anything else you may want, be that source code formatters, bundlers or a SASS compiler.

To use a configuration from `tasks.json`, you select Run Task from the command list.

**Here's an example of how they differ in purpose:**

I have an Angular 5 application that connects to a .NET web service.

I have one task configured to run the web service, using a command that fires up IISExpress. I have another task configured to run the Angular app using `ng serve`, which recompiles the app when files change. I execute these two tasks whenever I reopen VS Code, or when the web service changes.

I have two launch configurations as well: One to launch Chrome and start the debugger, and another to debug a page already loaded in Chrome. These I execute whenever I start a debug session.

Comment: not quite understood, For task.json, how to "select Run Task from the command list" in vscode? Is it on the debug pane? or ctrl+shift+p list?

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+shift+p, then type Run Task. It should then show you a list of the tasks available from tasks.json as well as package.json and other sources. This is for the US English version of vscode.